# How to get previous fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In order to reuse some fragments in my app, I need to know which Fragment is the second on the back stack.

In order to do that I'm using `getFragmentManager().getFragments()`, which shows the following error (but works!)

> FragmentManager.getFragments can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Is it safe to use? Could I get the same result by another approach?

Here is the code:

```
public Fragment getCallerFragment(){
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
    return fragments.get(fragments.size()-2);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we put both answers together, you can add TAG's to your fragments and get the previous Fragment name with this method:

```
private String getCallerFragment(){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        return fm.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 2).getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this method to get the number of counts in backStack

> getBackStackEntryCount()

use this method to get the fragments

> getBackStackEntryAt (int index)

you can also do something like

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

for(int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
   Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also put tag's / id's to fragments and get them by id

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
```

else 
Nouman Ch solution will work for you.