# FragmentManager.getFragments can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Using `FragmentManager.getFragments()` shows an error on Android Studio. Despite this, it compiles and works properly.

This is the error:

> FragmentManager.getFragments can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

In my [last OS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324922/how-to-get-previous-fragments), I asked for a workaround for the fragment count, but the suggested `.getBackStackEntryCount()` doesn't return the total number of fragments, so we cannot use `getBackStackEntryAt(int index)`.

Is it safe to use `FragmentManager.getFragments()`, even if it shows an error or it will be deprecated at some point?